# How to test (TDD) if a Symfony route return an array of products (with deserialization)

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, tdd

I'm writing a test that will check if a route returns an array of products (and it's a JSON).
But I don't know what's the good way to check it.

I tried:

```php
$products = $serializer->deserialize($content, 'App\Entity\Product[]', 'json');
$this->assertIsArray($products, 'is not an array');
$this->assertContainsOnlyInstancesOf(Product::class, $products, 'array does not contains only instance of Product');
```

But if my route return:`return $this->json(["foo"]);` The test will be correct. Maybe I can use a validator inside the test, but maybe it's not the way to write a TDD test for this goal.

How can I check before deserialization if the response content is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Serializer#deserialize()` won't necessarily fail if $content doesn't match up with $type, you'll need to check the JSON directly for the format you expect.

For example, if you expect 123 products with properties "foo" and "bar" in the response:

```php
$responseBody = $response->getBody();
$products = json_decode($responseBody);

$this->assertIsArray($products);
$this->assertCount(123, $products);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $this->assertIsObject($product);
    $this->assertTrue(property_exists($product, 'foo'));
    $this->assertTrue(property_exists($product, 'bar'));
}
```